# Android JobQueue - Queue jobs

Tags: android, android-priority-jobqueue

I have a simple scenario where I would like to queue two jobs, **Job A** and **Job B**.

**Job B** must only be called once **Job A** has finished.

**Setup**

I have encapsulated the `jobManager` object within `Application`.

`App.getJobManager().addJobInBackground(new JobA());`
`App.getJobManager().addJobInBackground(new JobB());`

**Job Constructor**

Both jobs typically have a constructor that looks like this:

```
public JobA() // or JobB
{
    super(new Params(1).requireNetwork());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give both of them the same `groupId` so that it will not run them parallel. Note that this will still run `Job B` even if `Job A` fails.

Comment: I think there's an issue about groupId if I use it with requiredNetwork param and run the job without network once network back It will not run sequentially. Can you please check this issue https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue/issues/374